# RegEx Replace with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm struggling with an issue of Javascript RegEx replacement. What I need to do is run a replacement over a paragraph of text looking for "[card]lorem ipsum[/card]"

I found jQuery plugins which allow for regex matching on selectors, such as ids or paragraphs containing text but I didn't find one which would get down to the actual regex text.

So then I went back to the original javascript level of RegEx and kept running into walls.

So can anyone help me?

I need to turn

```
[card]lorem ipsum[/card]
```

into

```
<a href="http://example.com/lorem+ipsum" class="card">lorem ipsum</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: is `[card]` a token name that should be added as link `class` so it can essentially be anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myString.replace(
    /\[card\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/card\]/g,
    function (_, cardContent) {
      return '<a href=\"http://example.com/' + encodeURIComponent(cardContent)
          + '" class="card">' + cardContent + '<\/a>';
    });
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
var rx = /\[card](.+?)\[\/card]/gi;
yourTextVariable.replace(rx, "<a href='http://example.com/$1'>$1</a>");
```

everything in between will be captured for you.

If *card* is a variable that should be inserted as class:

```
var rx = /\[(.+?)](.+?)\[\/.+?]/gi;
yourTextVariable.replace(rx, "<a href='http://example.com/$2' clas='$1'>$2</a>");
```

Comment: This will only replace the first instance and will not properly encode the URL. If the card content contains double quotes, it will break

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I've changed the *globalization* of the replacement and encoding has of course been done by U. No need for me to change my answer because it will be identical to yours. **But mine will also use token name to append to link class** which yours doesn't. ;)

Comment: Good catch.  I forgot that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "[card]lorem ipsum[/card]";
var r = '<a href="http://example.com/$2" class="$1">$2</a>';

var re = /\[(\w+)\](.+?)\[\/\w+\]/ig;

var n = s.replace(re, r); // Would have the result
```

Comment: This will only replace the first instance and will not properly encode the URL.  If the card content contains double quotes, it will break.

Comment: This will also treat `foo[/card][card]bar` as the card content of `[card]foo[/card][card]bar[/card]`.